# Save Pandas DataFrames with formulas to xlsx files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwt

In a Pandas DataFrame i have some "cells" with values and some that need to contain excel formulas. I have read that i can get formulas with

```
link = 'HYPERLINK("#Groups!A' + str(someInt) + '"; "LINKTEXT")'
xlwt.Formula(link)
```

and store them in the dataframe.

When i try to save my dataframe as an xlsx file with

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas" + str(fileCounter) + ".xlsx", engine = "xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Paths", index = False)
# insert more sheets here
writer.save()
```

i get the error:

```
TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'xlwt.ExcelFormula.Formula'> in write()
```

So i tried to write my formula as a string to my dataframe but Excel wants to restore the file content and then fills all formula cells with `0`'s.

**Edit:** I managed to get it work with regular strings but nevertheless would be interested in a solution for xlwt formulas.

So my question is: How do i save dataframes with formulas to xlsx files?

Comment: @Parfait i want to add hyperlinks to other cells to the df.

Comment: added formula content example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing the df using `table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=...)`, I use `write_formula()` as in this example (edited to add the full loop). To write all the formulas in your dataframe, read each formula in your dataframe.

```
 # replace the right side below with reading the formula from your dataframe
 # e.g., formula_to_write = df.loc(...)`

 rows = table.shape[0]
 for row_num in range(1 + startrow, rows + startrow + 1):
    formula_to_write = '=I{} * (1 - AM{})'.format(row_num+1, row_num+1) 
    worksheet.write_formula(row_num, col, formula_to_write)`
```

Later in the code (I seem to recall one of these might be redundant, but I haven't looked it up):
`writer.save() workbook.close()`

Documentation is [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html).

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using xlsxwriter, strings are parsed as formulas by default (["strings_to_formulas: Enable the worksheet.write() method to convert strings to formulas. The default is True"](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html)), so you can simply specify formulas as strings in your dataframe.

Example of a formula column which references other columns in your dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("foo.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df["product"] = None
df["product"] = (
    '=INDIRECT("R[0]C[%s]", 0)+INDIRECT("R[0]C[%s]", 0)'
    % (
        df.columns.get_loc("col1") - df.columns.get_loc("product"),
        df.columns.get_loc("col2") - df.columns.get_loc("product"),
    )
)
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Produces the following output:

[image: Example output in LibreOffice]

Comment: Is there any side effects for this solution? Why is there a `write_formula()` What is the difference?

Comment: It is worth noting that for relatively new formulas the `_xlfn.` prefix should be added. I encountered this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76334911/11485896.

Answer (score 0):

- you need to save in as usual just keep in mind to write the formula as string.
- you can use also f strings with vars.

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(FILE_PATH ,mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')
    
    col_Q_index = 3
    best_formula = f'=max(L1,N98,Q{col_Q_index})'
    formula_df = pd.DataFrame([[best_formula]])
    formula_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=SHEET_NAME, startrow=i, startcol=17, index=False, header=False)
    
    writer.save()
```